# Url link breaking up in text message Android Application

Tags: android, url, sms

i have a url link am trying to send to my user, but the link breaks up cause. it sends the full link but about half of it is not underlined as a link. this is what am trying to send

```
 String locateUrl="http://maps.google.com?q="+latitude()+","+longitude();
```

first it does not recognize this ?q= as a link and it just breaks up from there, have checked other answers and tried them but seems not to be working

Comment: What is the output of _locateUrl_?

Comment: this is the output [http://maps.google.com?q=-29.087074,23.753042]

Comment: Google maps shows a place near to douglas. Is that waht you did expect?

Comment: yes, the link is clickable here, but when sent as text the only clickable part is http://maps.google.com and it just breaks from there. ?q= becomes not clickabe

Comment: just checked seems to be coming from my message handler. cause it works perfectly well when sent via email and am using SmsManager

Comment: lol i just saw the solution, all i had to do was put this / before ?q. got it from the link i posted as a comment before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved this by putting "/" before ?q= thereby making sure the link doesn't break
full link will then be

`String locateUrl="http://maps.google.com/?q="+latitude()+","+longitude();`

Answer (score 0):

Your link may be breaking because of space at the beginning or in between trim it and then use it.

```
String locateUrl="http://maps.google.com?q="+latitude()+","+longitude();
locateUrl = locateUrl.trim();
```

Comment: just tried trimming, still the same thing, the format i used when sent via email it works perfectly well but through text message it gives this broken link